# zoom on mobile like desktop browser

Tags: javascript, css, mobile, zooming

I have a page, it dynamically flows using css % units. On the desktop if I resize the page looks beautiful, the text reflows making the page longer to accommodate. On the desktop if I zoom the page looks beautiful, everything gets bigger and reflows making the page longer to accommodate.

On mobile when I zoom the page stays the same aspect ratio, the whole thing gets bigger there is no reflow and it becomes a pane to use.

How do i get the zoom on mobile to reflow like on the desktop?

**Edit:**

---

After reading the links in RoyalleBlue comments I added the following tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

This tells mobile devices to initially flow to the "actual" width. This is a very good start. Good enuff that are client is happy with the "mobile site." But, it still zooms like a mobile devices: page stays the same aspect ratio the whole thing gets bigger and there is no reflow. So I'm still in search of an answer.

Comment: Do you prefer the solution to use [media queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) or would you prefer not to use them?

Comment: I have used them in other parts of the webpage. so I have no objection to using them here, if they will help.

Comment: Depending on how many CSS selectors you need to specify for the media, you may consider using a [max-width query just for phones](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cssmediaqueries2.shtml).  The typical phone will be less than 480px.  In that case, I'd suggest putting a link at the bottom to allow users to toggle between "Desktop CSS" and "Mobile CSS."  That's all I know so I thought I'd share, hope it helps you get closer to what you were looking for.

Comment: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

Answer (score 1):

Using Responsive metatag you can able to do this

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">
```